# Argument wrong type and are out of Acaptable range file:///c:/Tools/MYScript.hta

Tags: html, sql-server, vbscript

I am writing a script to query MSSQL DB and Display content for that DB. However, I am getting error as **Argument wrong type** and are **out of Acaptable range**. Please help me ..

Following is the **script:**

```
sub GetProcesses
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open _ 
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=.;" & _ 
    "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ILO_1;" & _ 
    "User ID=sa;Password=Test@123;" 

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ILO WHERE DeviceName ='" & enteredText & "'"
    objRecordSet.Open strsql, _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    'objRecordSet.MoveFirst
    Set rs = objRecordSet
    WHILE rs.EOF <> TRUE 
        CI_w= rs("DeviceName")
        ILOIP_w= rs("ILO IP")
        Username_w= rs("User")
        Password_w= rs("PASSWORD")
        rs.movenext
END SUB
```

Comment: Which line is raising the error(s) and what are the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript does not pre-define constants like adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, ... . Make sure they are properly defined.